# Input doesn't match pass code when they are the same

Tags: python

I just started python last week and made this code project to test my learning. This code is supposed to display a Zombie Apocalypse and the user arrives at the military base. While proving that they are human, the code generates a random 5 number pass code to make the game unique every time. The user has to type to code in, kind of like a CAPTCHA. But when I run the code, after the user types the pass code and presses enter, the pass code entering part of the code starts to repeat. I think this may be because of the while loop if the user gets the pass code wrong. I don't have much experience to see the problem. I tried rewriting the whole thing, it didn't even try to work because of so many syntax error messages. If you can please help me it would be appreciated.

I also am working on it on replit, so you can check the code there:
https://replit.com/@PratikKharel/Something2?v=1

```
import time
import sys
import random


def typing(text):
    for character in text:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.07)


def fasttyping(text):
    for character in text:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.02)


def fastertyping(text):
    for character in text:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.005)


passcode = "".join(str(random.randint(1, 9)) for _ in range(5))
typing("Hello fellow surviver.")
time.sleep(0.8)
print("")
typing("Welcome to the Zombie Military Base: ")
time.sleep(0.8)
print("")
typing("Lambda 17 ")
time.sleep(1)
print("")
typing("This is where you will begin your survival story. ")
print("")
time.sleep(1)
passwordright = False
typing(f"Type [{passcode}] to verify as a Human")
time.sleep(0.5)
typing(".")
time.sleep(0.3)
typing(".")
time.sleep(0.3)
typing(".")
time.sleep(0.3)


def start():
    print("")
    typing(">>> ")
    o = (int(input("")))
    if o != passcode:
        typing("Please try again.")
        print("")
        start()
    elif o == passcode:
        passwordright = True
        fasttyping("#@$____!#%$!@___WE_ARE_COMING_FOR_YOU__@$@#$___@#$")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        fastertyping(
            '\r____________________________________________________________')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("")
        typing("Since you are here, you will need a nickname.")
        print("")
        fasttyping("What will !@#$%^&@")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        fastertyping('\rWhat will your name be?')
    while passwordright == False:
        start()


start()
```

Comment: please fix your indentation and provide a [mre]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please check the indentation of your Python code?

Comment: I think indentation is good now, sorry im new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to compare between different data types at:

```
if o != passcode:
```

`o` is of type `int`, while `passcode` is a string.

Just delete the `int` casting in `o = (int(input("")))` to:

```
o = (input())
```

Comment: Thank you, It works now. I don't know why i put o = int(input("")) there, maybe I thought that passcode would also be an int because passcode= "".join(str(random.randint(1, 9)) for _ in range(5)) has int in it. :)

Comment: @SomeonenamedPratik Personally I don't use numerical types if I don't perform any mathematical operations, glad to hear it works! don't forget to accept this as your answer :).